# Allow access only to Googlebot - robots.txt

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, googlebot

I want to allow access to a single crawler to my website - the Googlebot one. In addition, I want Googlebot to crawl and index my site according to the sitemap only.

Is this the right code?

I know that Only "good" bots follow the robots.txt instructions but still..it's a start point

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want for the `robots.txt` (see more examples in [this doc](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en))

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```